# How to access $scope in service in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently trying to post tweet via using Twitter API directly from my website but I am new to Angular and having some issues regarding passing a parameter in the url.
I want to pass status variable into the url becuase I'll be getting input from textarea.

**service.js**

```
angular.module('twitterApp.services', [])
.factory('twitterService', function($q, $scope){
    var authorizationResult = false;

    return {
        initialize: function() {
            OAuth.initialize('#OAuth Key here', {cache: true});
            authorizationResult = OAuth.create('twitter');
        },
        isReady: function() {
            return(authorizationResult);
        },
        connectTwitter: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            OAuth.popup('twitter', {cache: true}, function(error, result){
               if(!error){
                   authorizationResult = result;
               } 
                else{
                    //Do Something else if there's an error
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            });
        },
        clearCache: function() {
            OAuth.clearCache('twitter');
            authorizationResult = false;
        },
        postTweet() {
            var status = $scope.textModel;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = authorizationResult.post('/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=' + 'status').done(function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my controller where I declared the variable, I am pretty sure that I am wrong but I need to know the solution for this.
**Controller**:

```
app.controller('TwitterController', function($scope, $q, twitterService) {

    $scope.textModel = "";

    twitterService.initialize();

    $scope.postTweet = function() {
        var status = $scope.textModel;
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="twitterApp">
<head>
    <title>Twitter OAuth.io Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="oauth.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script src="services.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container text-center" ng-controller="TwitterController">
        <h1>Tweet..</h1>
        <span><i>Or rather just do it more than classic version.</i></span>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <textarea placeholder="What's on your mind?" id="tweetBox" rows="10" ng-model="textModel"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg" id="tweetButton" ng-click="postTweet()">Tweet</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            Your tweet will appear like this:
        </div>
        <div>
            " {{textModel}} "
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are faceing with?

Comment: @Sarkhan I want to write something in textarea and submit it to twitter as a status. The problem is I have to pass it in url, in order to do that so I made variable as 'status' that can hold the value of textarea as $scope.textModel. But I don't know how to pass it in url as url is in services and my variable is in controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an argument to your `postTweet` function.

Part of your Service:

```
postTweet(text) {
        var status = text;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = authorizationResult.post('/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=' + 'status').done(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

And your Controller:

```
app.controller('TwitterController', function($scope, $q, twitterService) {

    $scope.textModel = "";

    twitterService.initialize();

   $scope.postTweet = function() {
       twitterService.postTweet($scope.textModel);
   }
});
```

Comment: I totally got the concept but I am still getting an error. I don't know why though.

Comment: Hey! I really need help with my code right now. Can you please help?

Comment: Yes, I can. What do you need?

Comment: Yes, of course. The tweet is limited to 144 chars, but it is another problem, right? You need to post another question. This current question was answered. Please,  mark this answer as right and open another question.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the answer above is correct, I just want to add that it's important to handle the error in the service or at the very least in the controller, right now only deferred.resolve() is being called on success. You should capture any twitter error and do a deferred.reject(err)
So your controller looks like:

```
$scope.postTweet = function() {
       twitterService.postTweet($scope.textModel)
       .then( data => console.log(data) )
       .catch( err => console.error(err) );
   }
```

I'm sure there are better ways to handle success/error than console.log but you get the idea I hope, don't forget the error case.

Comment: Sure, but I am getting an error. Can you please help?